# How to use namespace urls with django in a reusuable app

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a django app, a forum app, that has templates with it. In those templates, there are urls that point to parts of the app. For instance the thread_list template has links to each thread like so:

```
{% for thread in threads %}
    <a href="{% url forum_thread thread %}">{{thread.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The thing is, I don't really like calling my urls "forum_thread". I prefer just "thread" and using the namespace feature of django. "forum_thread" may be used somewhere else in the project (namespace collision).So it will look like this:

```
{% for thread in threads %}
    <a href="{% url forum:thread thread %}">{{thread.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

but this doesn't feel like the correct way to do this. The docs are kind of unclear here.

I want this app to be reusable and easy to configure. But I also want to use the best standards. I don't want to have the to make the user specify their own namespace name, and then have them edit every single url in each template.

How should I do urls in this app?

Comment: I have exactly the same dilema!
 Bump!

Comment: Did you ever up with anything?  I'm experiencing the same issue and not sure how things should be done.

Answer (score 15):

From what I can gather you should be able use {% url forum:thread thread %} as you've described. Namespaces always seem to be defined with two variables, namespace and app_name.

If you then do the following in urls.py:

```
url(r'^/forum/', include('forum.urls', namespace='forum', app_name='forum')),
url(r'^/foo/', include('forum.urls', namespace='foo', app_name='forum')),
url(r'^/bar/', include('forum.urls', namespace='bar', app_name='forum')),
```

In my understanding, this defines 3 instances of the app 'forum', 'foo', 'bar', and the default (which has namespace==app_name).

When you reverse forum:thread, it uses the current context to determine which one to use- if you are in namespace 'foo' it will use that, otherwise it will fall back on the default.

If anyone is able to clarify how Django decides what the 'current' namespace/app is that would be very helpful. I currently categorise it as 'black magic'.

Some clarification on the actual difference between namespace and app_name would also be helpful- it's possible that I have this totally reversed. The current docs are highly ambiguous.

Note: I have this working for initial requests, but I'm currently unable to make this work for AJAX requests- those always use the default instance for some reason.

Comment: This is now specified in the docs and it looks like you have it correct: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls  I think it's not necessary to specify `app_name='forum'` unless you want to use something different from the module name. I'm guessing if not working for AJAX requests it's maybe because you are rendering the response differently (perhaps not using a template or not using RequestContext) and so the current app needs to be manually specified when reversing the urls.

Comment: The problem is that this urls can be included in the root urls only. I.e. there is an _app_ with a _site_ app included in the root urls
_app/urls.py_: `url(r'^/site/', include('site.urls', namespace='site', app_name='site')`,
_site_ app includes forum:
`url(r'^/forum/', include('forum.urls', namespace='forum', app_name='forum'))`
It breaks forum as its urls cannot be reversed as 'forum:*' but 'site:forum'*'

Answer (score 3):

based on my understanding of this question:

> in Django 2.1.7

- **You can app name in app's urls.py file**

```py
# app's urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'forum'
urlpatterns = [
    path('thread/', views.mark_done, name='thread')
]
```

in main urls.py

```py
# urls.py
....

urlpatterns = [
    path('forum/', include('forum.urls')),
]
```

then you can employ `{% url 'forum:thread' %}` in your template

- **If you wanna use it in a for loop**

I think we should

1. create a view return all `threads` as context
2. then add a path to that view

```
...
path('thread/<int:pk>', views.mark_done, name='thread')
```

the url in template will like:

```
{% for thread in threads %}
    <a href="{% url 'forum:thread' thread.id %}">{{thread.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a simple syntax error. I was following the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/), and I changed mysite/urls.py improperly. The original syntax:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

The desired change:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
```

What I did:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'), namespace="polls"),
```

Correcting the syntax resolved the issue.