# Refer to my (reusable) app's url namespace in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to write a reusable Django application.

I tell my users to add the following to their `urls.py`

`path('slack/', include(('slack_integration.urls', 'slack_integration'), namespace='slack_integration'),`

And in my `urls.py` I want to have a view `login_callback`.

Now in my view, I need to get a value of `slack_integration:login_callback`.

I can trust the user that he/she will integrate it with `slack_integration` prefix and use it. But is this the best practise? Can I somehow get the name of the namespace for the app if user chooses a different name for it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've checked a few popular django libraries, like allauth for example, and they do not use namespaces at all. As long as you document what they need to do, it should be fine. But you can also look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155733/how-to-use-namespace-urls-with-django-in-a-reusuable-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `namespace=` within `urls.py` files is no longer supported, as it moves something specific to the Django app outside of the Python package that is the Django app.

The best practice now is to define the `app_name` within the `urls.py` file inside the Django app.

**The old way: DON'T DO THIS (pre-Django 2.0)**

*the root urls.py*

```py
path('slack/', include(('slack_integration.urls', 'slack_integration'), namespace='slack_integration'),
```

**The new way: DO THIS! (Django 2.0+)**

*the root urls.py*

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('slack/', include(('slack_integration.urls', 'slack_integration')),
]
```

*slack_integration/urls.py*

```py
from django.urls import path

app_name = "slack_integrations"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

As you can see, this keeps the namespace for the patterns within the app itself, along with the templates most likely to use it. The days of extra instructions on how to include an app are over! Good luck.