# Not Understood an Aspect of Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

So you see I'm learning the basics of Django from a course on YouTube by Rafeh Qazi. 
 In that course we were making a polls application following the Django at a glace documentation. 
 So on the third video we talked about something called **Namespacing URL names**. And I didn't quit understand it. Can anyone please tell me about it You See here is how the tree view of my project look like:

```
    ## Django Crash Course ##
       -> ### mysite ### 
          > folder: _pycache_
          > __init__.py
          > asgi.py
          > settings.py
          > urls.py
          > wsgi.py

       -> ### polls ###
          > folder: _pycache_
          > folder: migrations
          > folder: templates
             > folder: polls
                 > index.html
                 > detail.html
          > __init__.py
          > admin.py
          > apps.py
          > models.py
          > test.py
          > urls.py
          > views.py
       > .gitignore
       > db.sqlite
       > manage.py
```

I may not be able to show you the images of my code I can take you there:
follow this link: [My Github project](https://github.com/KidCoderT/Django_Crash_Course-CP_Lessons)

Comment: Take a look at this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/55253148/1199464

Answer (score 0):

As your project grows you may have up to 20 or so apps and each one of those apps can have different URLs.

For example, you can have a page called *home* under your *polls* app and a page called the same under another app called *someapp*.

If you don't use namespaces a call to home page in a template can have issues but with namespaces, you can use them in templates by mentioning the app name before it (like `'polls:home'`).

Comment: But the instructor said that the reason he put a polls folder inside the templates folder  was because that would do the same thing. Is that also a way to do it???

Comment: sorry about the delay. the folder stuff is for django's templating system, not the URLs.

Comment: Thanks, Realy sorry for the delay